# Display random message after post-receive hook from array

Tags: linux, git, bash

I want it to select one item from array and display it, right now it is displaying them all.

Here is what I have at the end of the post-receive hook:

```
# Array with expressions
expressions=("You upload" "Dude what's that smell?" "Some Bytes are Missing!")

# Seed random generator
RANDOM=$$$(date +%s)

# Get random expression...
selectedexpression=${expressions[$RANDOM % ${#expressions[@]} ]}

# Write to Shell
echo $selectedexpression
```

Comment: Ahah! I added in commas between each array item, removing them fixed it! Thanks that helped me realize my problem!

Comment: Don't seed the random number generator on every call. You shouldn't have to seed it at all.

Comment: @rici : so deleting line: RANDOM=$$$(date +%s) will be fine?